# Sending data async over network with prefetching in .NET

Tags: .net, networking, asynchronous, streaming

If you have ever used SQL Server Management Studio, you would have noticed how query results begin to show in the viewer before the query is finished and all results are received by the client.

I am looking to implement (reuse) that functionality for my own data store / data streaming farm.

- Client sends a query to the server and gets back an IEnumerable (4.0 IObservable?)
- Client iterates over it until a) end of stream or b) Client explicitly cancels the query
- Asynchronously, a separate thread on the client continues to receive data, but no more than some buffer would allow.
- If no new data is available, client should be able to either block / get notified / busy poke.

Are there any libraries like that? Are ADO providers implement something similar? Streaming engines?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Recommend you run SQL Profiler to trace activity of your session.  Something like "fast first row" option starts data streaming back quickly.  You will need to implement async code to handle chunks of data.  IOW you can't fill a data set this way and use it while it's filling.

Comment: Didn't understand about SQL Profile -- I have my own data store, and my own data access lib, so I do not have to use ADO or any other tech like that unless they provide built-in ahead-of-time block read functionality.